# Screenshot of test application in Appium Inspector

Tags: android, testing, selenium-webdriver, android-virtual-device, appium

I have launched an android emulator (avd) with appium using selenium webdriver (python script) on mac os x.
It installs a test application and opens it.
When I open the appium inspector it does not show any screenshots of the application. What should I do to see the application screenshot in Appium Inspector? the avd is of api level 19.

Comment: Try to use genymotion instead android default avd emulator. Worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have checked "Emulation Option" "Use Host GPU option"?
If yes; that could be the reason you are not seeing screenshot. Edit/create the AVD without "Emulation Option" "Use Host GPU option" checked as shown in image:

[image]